# issues with my java project

Tags: java, methods

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

I have to create the player class for a basic "adventuring" game we are making as a group project in java class.  Eclipse is telling me that my get and set methods (getStr, getAgi, etc) all need a semicolon to finish the block.  but I know that cannot be right.  any help or advice in general?

```
public class playerChars extends JPanel{



private int str, agi, intell, hitP;
private String wep, arm;


die sixSidedDie = new die(6);

{
public int getStr(str)
{
    str = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
public int getAgi(agi)
{
    agi = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
public int roll(intell)
{
    intell = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
public int getHitP(hitP)
{
    hitP = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
}

public static int setQuant(int quantity)
{
    int quant;
    quant = quantity;
}
public String getWep()
{
    return wep;
}
public String setWep(String weapon)
{
    this.wep = weapon;
}
public String getArm()
{
    String armor;
    return armor;
}
public String setArm(String armor)
{
    this.arm = armor;
}
public int setPot(int potion)
{
    int pot;
    pot = potion;
}
public int getPot()
{
    int potion;
    return potion;
}

}
```

Comment: You should learn basic java first. This isn't even proper formatting.

Comment: can you give me any suggestions as to the proper formatting?

Comment: This is an issue with basic Java fundamentals... You obviously don't know any Java at all, take it slowly.

Comment: Java does not use pass-by-reference

Comment: well yeah I've only been doing java for about.. 10 weeks.  and not every day, as much as I wish I could.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting that error is because you have a  `{` curly above your first method with a curly after another intermediate method, which is a [`block`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html) in Java. The block is expecting to have statements, not method declarations.

```
{ //<--
public int getStr(str)
{
    str = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
...
    public int getHitP(hitP)
{
    hitP = sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
} //<--
```

Remove them and you should be ok. However, Your methods are incomplete as the other answerer has mentioned.

From the doc --

> A block is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces and can be used anywhere a single statement is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Your getters need to look like this:

```
public int getStr()
{
    return sixSidedDie.getValue();
}
```